# Why is the move constructor neither declared nor deleted with clang?

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-functions, move-semantics, implicit-declaration

Consider the following classes.

```
struct with_copy {
    with_copy() = default;
    with_copy(with_copy const&) {}
    with_copy& operator=(with_copy const&) { return *this; }
};

struct foo {
    with_copy c;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
};
```

- Does `with_copy` have a copy constructor? Yes. It was explicitly defined.
- Does `with_copy` have a move constructor? No. The explicit copy constructor prevents it from being generated.
- Does `with_copy` have a deleted move constructor? No. Not having a move constructor is not the same as having a deleted one. A deleted move constructor would make an attempt to move ill-formed instead of degenerating to a copy.
- Is `with_copy` copyable? Yes. Its copy constructor is used for copies.
- Is `with_copy` movable? Yes. Its copy constructor is used for moves.

... and now the tricky ones.

- Does `foo` have a copy constructor? Yes. It has a deleted one, as its defaulted definition would be ill-formed due to invoking `unique_ptr`'s deleted copy constructor.
- Does `foo` have a move constructor? GCC says yes, clang says no.
- Does `foo` have a deleted move constructor? Both GCC and clang say no.
- Is `foo` copyable? No. Its copy constructor is deleted.
- Is `foo` movable? GCC says yes, clang says no.

(The behaviour is similar when one considers assignment instead of construction.)

As far as I can see, GCC is correct. `foo` should have a move constructor that performs a move on each member, which in `with_copy`'s case degenerates to a copy. Clang's behaviour seems quite ridiculous: I have an aggregate with two movable members, and yet my aggregate is an immovable brick.

Who's right?

Comment: technically, I think the Standardese is that the `with_copy` copy constructor is *user-provided*

Comment: In n3485, [class.copy]/11 says the move ctor is deleted if "for the move constructor, a non-static data member or direct or virtual base class with a type that
does not have a move constructor and is not trivially copyable." And `with_copy` is not trivially copyable.

Comment: @DyP no compiler makes a deleted move constructor though :S (And ffs those rules are ridiculous)

Comment: Because an implicitly deleted move constructor is not declared, /9.

Comment: Btw, this changes in C++1y. The recent draft in the github repo says `foo` has a move-constructor, as far as I understand it.

Comment: @DyP can you collect your findings as an answer?

Comment: [DR1402](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1402)

Answer (score 8):

C++11, or rather n3485, [class.copy]/9:

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared
>   as defaulted if and only if
>
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared destructor, and
> - the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.

and /11:

> An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is an `inline public` member of its class. A defaulted copy/
>   move constructor for a class `X` is defined as deleted (8.4.3) if `X` has:
>
> - [...]
> - for the copy constructor, a non-static data member of rvalue reference type, or
> - for the move constructor, a non-static data member or direct or virtual base class with a type that
>     does not have a move constructor and is not trivially copyable.

As `with_copy` is *not* trivially copyable, `foo` will have *no* move-constructor (it would be defined as deleted, therefore it won't be implicitly declared).

---

C++1y, or rather github repo commit e31867c0 from 2013-11-12; incorporating [DR1402](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1402):

/9:

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move
>   constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only
>   if
>
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
> - `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.

and /11:

> An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is an `inline public`
>   member of its class. A defaulted copy/ move constructor for a class `X`
>   is defined as deleted (8.4.3) if `X` has:
>
> - [...]
> - for the copy constructor, a non-static data member of rvalue reference type.
>
> A defaulted move constructor that is defined as deleted is ignored by
>   overload resolution (13.3, 13.4).

Here, `foo` will have a move-constructor.

Comment: `std::is_move_constructible<T>` is defined as `is_constructible<T, T&&>` which in turn just checks if `T(declval<T>())` is well-formed. So a type with no declared move ctor (or a move ctor that is ignored during overload resolution) is still "movable" in the sense of `std::is_move_constructible`.

Comment: CWG 1402 is (imho) the most important bug fix to C++11 there is.  Tip-of-trunk clang implements it, even in -std=c++11 mode.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not quite sure what you tested but it `foo` is surely both move assignable and move constructible. Admittedly, this doesn't say anything about a move constructor or a move assignment being accessible, just that construction or assignment from an rvalue works. Both [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (clang version 3.5 (trunk 196718)) and [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (gcc version 4.9.0 20131031 (experimental) (GCC)) agree with this assessment. This is the complete source I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

struct with_copy {
    with_copy() = default;
    with_copy(with_copy const&) {}
    with_copy& operator=(with_copy const&) { return *this; }
};

struct foo {
    with_copy c;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "move constructible: "
              << std::is_move_constructible<foo>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "move assignable: "
              << std::is_move_assignable<foo>::value << '\n';
    foo f0;
    foo f1 = std::move(f0);
    f0 = std::move(f1);
}
```