# Move constructor is automatic generated even a member doesn't have a move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Quoted from *C++ Primer*

> if we explicitly ask the compiler to generate a move operation by
>   using `= default`, and the compiler is unable to move all the
>   members, then the move operation will be defined as deleted
>
> the move constructor is defined as deleted **if the
>   class has a member that defines its own copy constructor but does not also
>   define a move constructor**, or if the class has a member that doesn’t define its
>   own copy operations and for which the compiler is unable to synthesize a move
>   constructor

Some code seems to violate this rule:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    X() = default;
    X(const X&) { std::cout << "X(const X&)" << std::endl; }
    int i;
};

struct hasX {
    hasX() = default;
    hasX(const hasX &) = delete;
    hasX(hasX &&) = default;
    X mem;
};


int main()
{
    hasX hx, hx2 = std::move(hx);  //output is X(const X&)
}
```

`X` doesn't define move constructor and compiler can't synthesize one for it.

According to the rule above, `hasX`'s move constructor is deleted.

However, because `hasX`'s copy constructor is deleted, `hx2 = std::move(hx)` must call move constructor to output `"X(const X&)"`, which shows `hasX`'s move constructor is defined and it use `X`'s copy constructor to "move". This seems to violate the rule above.

So, is't defined in C++ standard or just a compiler implementation?

Compiler I tested: VS2015 and [a online compiler](http://cpp.sh/7rwdy)

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your book seems to be wrong.  [Copying is a valid move operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939644/understanding-stdis-move-constructible) so as long as the member has a copy constructor in the form of `const type&`, so it can bind to rvalues, the move operation will fall back to a copy.

In your example

```
hasX(hasX &&) = default;
```

Can be replaced with

```
hasX(hasX &&rhs) : mem(std::move(rhs.mem)) {}
```

as that is what the default does and it will compile just fine.

Comment: Can you give me a standard reference to support this? I'm having trouble backing up the claim. The standard appears to me to specify otherwise (N3337 12.8/11, 9/6, 12.8/12)

Comment: @AndyG The linked to answer has all the quotes to back up my assertion.  Also what about 12.8/11 makes you think it is not allowed?

Comment: I find that "a non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) that cannot be **copied/moved** because overload resolution".

Comment: @NathanOliver: The part about references in the linked answer clears things up, but honestly it reads to me like there's a contradiction in the standard. 12.8/11 states that a defaulted move constructor is deleted if `X` has a non-static data member that does not have a move constructor and is not trivially copyable. Of course it doesn't have a move ctor because it has a user-provided copy ctor. And it's not trivially copyable (9/6) because it has a user-provided copy ctor (12.8/12)

Comment: @AndyG I think your reading 12.8/11 wrong.  It states *a non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) that cannot be copied/moved because overload resolution[...]*  It says *copied/moved*. There is no requirement that it be trivial.

Comment: @AndyG Never mind,  it was me.  I think the line you are referencing was removed with a DR.  *for the move constructor, a non-static data member or direct or virtual base class with a type that does not have a move constructor and is not trivially copyable.* does not exist starting in at least N3690.

Comment: Found a DR from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20609313/4342498)

Comment: @NathanOliver: You are, of course, correct. The bullet point I cited is a few down from the one you just mentioned. The two have no stated precedence, but I think that it's clear the one you cited should take precedence over the one I cited.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Wow 2 comments in the time it took me to write that last one! So it seems that the wording was changed between N3337 and the published standard?

Comment: @AndyG Yes.  It was a defect on the standard and has been recitifed.  IIRC DR's backdated to the standard they are for so it applies to the C++11 standard.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Excellent research. Maybe the book that OP cites was not wrong when it was written :-)

Comment: @AndyG Could be.  Think I should change that part?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Nah, your statement is technically correct.